# Server performance affected by MySQL memory consuption and CPU usage

Tags: linux, mysql, performance, memory

Everyday during the peak time my server getting slow or down. Our hosting provider insisting us to upgrade the server but I think some performance tuning issue is there.

Adding the  process information, server configuration and my.cnf parameters below.

**Process Information**

```
 PID  USER       PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                  
 60848 mysql     20   0 34.8g  23g 6416 S 2196.2 82.1  16027:29 mysqld
```

**Dedicated Server Configuration**

```
Size:   'Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz', 2600MHz, 6 Core, Sockets: 2    
Image:  CentOS 6 64-bit with cPanel Fully-managed   
CPU:    Intel Dual Xeon E5-2620 v3
Speed:  2600MHz 
RAM:    32067MB 
CPUs:   2 Physical CPUs
Cores:  12 
Total Cores RAID:   Level 10
Disks:  4
Size:   917GB   
Type:   SSD
```

**MySQL Configuration**

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log = 1
#long_query_time = 2
long_query_time = 2
slow_query_log_file = /var/lib/mysql/vps-slow.log
performance-schema=0
max_connections = 250
max_allowed_packet=128M
#skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 256M
open_files_limit = 50000
table_open_cache = 15000
sort_buffer_size = 6M
join_buffer_size = 6M
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 15M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_limit=2M
query_cache_size=128M
max_heap_table_size = 96M
tmp_table_size = 96M
#low_priority_updates=1

thread_cache_size = 32
wait_timeout = 300
connect_timeout=15
interactive_timeout = 800

innodb_buffer_pool_size=4096M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4

group_concat_max_len=1000000

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqldump]
quick
```

Please help me if there is anything wrong with the configuration ?

**Or**

Do I really need to upgrade the server ?

PS: Hosted  web application in the same server. Also WHM enabled for easy management.

Comment: What does your overall memory consumption look like at the time this happens?  How about CPU utilization?  Disk I/O?

Comment: MySQL is really busy. Optimize your database queries.

Comment: @David, I could see MySQL is taking most the resources cpu and memory. I couldn't find the exact Disk I/O on peak time

Comment: You can use the [`Performance schema`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html) to find the queries that cause your problems, but every optimization has its limits. Does your server have SSD or magnetic drives? What is the number of requests per second/minute/hour. There's always a chance your hosting provider might actually be right.

Comment: @Jyothish Please add to your original question (or post in pastebin.com) Additional information request,  
current complete my.cnf/ini 
Text results of: 
A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
C) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop   OR  top for most active apps 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device
free -m  for a linux/unix free memory report
complete MySQLTuner.com  report if available.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from 4096M  - instances will be evenly divisible
#sort_buffer_size=6M  lead with # for default
#read_buffer_size=1M  lead with # for default
#read_rnd_buffer_size=15M  lead with # for default
#join_buffer_size=6M  lead with # for default
query_cache_min_res_unit=512  # from 4096 default to reduce QC RAM required per SELECT
```

Please use MySQLCalculator.com for 2 minutes to recognize your X per connection values are much higher than necessary to have a more predicatable instance of MySQL.

Also, if you could post complete report from 
A) ulimit -a        for your Linux OS limits 
 and 
B) Mysqltuner.com   complete report;

we would have helpful information, including the version of MySQL you are running, by ENGINE table data space and count of tables, all helpful information.  Thanks